# Search function unable to find formula result

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to do a search macro to find a specific date in a table. However the dates in the table are set in weeks by adding 7 from the previous date. So if `A1` is `1/1/2018` then `A2` would be `A1+7`, resulting in `1/8/2018`, so on and forth. I have added `LookIn:=xlValues` in the search function but the search still does not return any results. Would greatly appreciate some help.

This is the code I am using:

```
target_date = Cells(2, 20).Value

Set finding = Cells.Find(What:=target_date, After:=Cells(1, 1), LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:= _
    xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False _
    , SearchFormat:=False)

If Not finding Is Nothing Then finding.Activate
```

Comment: If you write `target_date = Cells(20, 2).Value`, would it work? `Instead of Cells(2,20)`

Comment: What's the exact value you've entered in cell `T2`?  I'm having no problem finding the cell with the code - declaring `target_date` as a variant or date and `finding` as a variant or range works.  The correct sheet is active when you perform the find?  You've not qualified the cells with a sheet reference so maybe something to consider.

Comment: Does the value in `T2` contain a time part while the list of dates doesn't? If so try using `target_date = Int(Cells(2, 20))`.

Comment: The value for `Cells(2, 20)` is `1/1/2018` format that is set to display as `1-Jan-18`. I have no problem searching for `1/1/2018`  but when I tried to search for `1/8/2018` there will be no results found.

Comment: Also, if I changed `A2` into `1/8/2018` instead of `=A1+7`, the search function is able to locate the cell.